# How do I disable default exception mappers?

Tags: dropwizard

My problem is that I want the same exception handling for all exceptions using DropWizard, and for this purpose I register an exception mapper for Exception. But exceptions for the default exceptions mappers, e.g. JDBI are not caught by my exception mapper due to the default exception mappers.

As stated in the documentation, DropWizard registers a number of default exception mappers. The documentation c.f. https://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/core.html#overriding-default-exception-mappers suggests setting server.registerDefaultExceptionMappers to false in the yml configuration.
I cannot get this to work though, which seems to have been a problem for others as well: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/2380.
The problem stated is a year old - does anybody know the current status of whether registerDefaultExceptionMappers  is supposed to disable the default exception mappers?